# How would I fix Blitz Basic Expecting End of File?

Tags: blitz3d

Brand new to working with computers, starting with something easy. Going through the Blitz3D Blitz BASIC tutorials. Been experimenting a bit with arrays but I keep getting the error: Expecting end of file error.
I'm not sure what's causing it. I also occasionally get "End of line error"
Here is the code:

```
Print "bricks"
AppTitle "Test"


A$ = "Hello"
B$ = " World"
C$ = A$ + B$
Print C$

MathTestAnswer = 14

; Days of the week------------------

    Dim day$(6)
day$(0) = "Monday "
day$(1) = "Tuesday "
day$(2) = "Wednesday "
day$(3) = "Thursday "
day$(4) = "Friday "
day$(5) = "Saturday "
day$(6) = "sunday "


Events$ = "Schools out!"
Summary$ = day$(4) + Events$ + " Hell yeah!"

Print Summary$

;Print day$(4) (not needed)

; END DAYS OF THE WEEK -------------

Print " "
Print " "

;Another Test array ------------------

    Dim MathTest(1)
MathTest(0) = 22 + MathTestAnswer)
MathTest(1) = 4



For MathTest = 0 To 1
Print MathTest(loop)
Next
```

Comment: MathTestAnswer = 14


 Dim MathTest(1)
MathTest(0) = 22 + MathTestAnswer)
MathTest(1) = 4



For MathTest = 0 To 1
Print MathTest(loop)
Next 

This seems to be the error in question. It's somewhere in here. Adding an End does not help same with it. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a spelling mistake. I added a(n) ) on accident. that caused it to not register the code.
It's not just that but the identifier "MathTest" cannot be used like this. Meaning I must have screwed up the array somewhere.